# MSXML / ServerXmlHttp POST Failing intermittently (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, http-post, msxml, winhttp, serverxmlhttp

I have some legacy Delphi code that POSTs XML to a secure web server using the MSXML component.

The code has been working fine for years.  Recently, we made some changes that makes the XML file size a bit larger, but not by much.  The XML size itself is still relatively small, eg, 100k or less.

We checked the server logs and the failure is an authentication error due to the fact that user/pass are *sometimes* not passed.  This happens intermittently.  The only thing that has changed is that the XML size has grown a bit.

I can verify this by incrementally growing an xml file until the POST fails.  I can also verify by doing the reverse, (ie, taking a large file and incrementally reducing it until it POSTs successfully).

Here is some sample code below.  In this case I load the xml from file.  In the actual code we use streams, but I am certain this is not the issue.

Does anyone know why the authentication data would get lost on the way to the https server?  I seem to recall something about MSXML having problems with negotiating authentication in certain cases, but I don't think it had to do with the size of the XML being Posted.

```
procedure TForm1.IntermittentFail; 
Var   
  Resp   : TStringStream ;   
  ole : OleVariant;   
  HTTPParams: TStrings;   
  aStream : TStream;   
  FXMLDoc     : TXMLDocument ;   
  FXMLResp    : TXMLDocument;   
  user, pass, URL, CommonStr : string;
begin
  if not(odXMLFile.Execute) then
    exit;
  user := 'JoeUser';   
  pass := 'password   
  URL      := 'https://aURL.com';   
  CommonStr := 'ParameterString';
  FXMLDoc      := TXMLDocument.Create(Nil);// create the outgoing doc  
  FXMLResp     :=   TXMLDocument.Create(Nil);// create the response doc
  Resp := nil;   
  FXMLDoc.LoadFromFile(odXMLFile.FileName);
  ole := CreateOleObject('MSXML2.ServerXmlHttp');
  ole.open('POST' ,URL , false, user, pass);
  ole.SetTimeouts( 0, 60000, 300000, 300000); 
//ole.SetTimeouts( 300000, 300000, 300000, 300000);  //no effect.
  ole.setOption(3, CommonStr); 
//ole.setrequestheader('connection', 'close');  //no effect //sleep(5000);                                  //no effect
ole.Send(FXMLDoc.XML.Text);   //THIS WILL INTERMITTENTLY FAIL.
  Resp  := TStringStream.Create(ole.ResponseText);
  finally
    ole := Unassigned;
    if Assigned(Resp) then   
      Resp.Free;
    FXMLDoc.Free;
    FXMLResp.Free;
  end; 
end;
```

Thank you -

Comment: What is the failure HRESULT code? And for the hell of it, what happens if you try using `IServerXmlHttpRequest` (i.e. maybe it's an late binding `IDispatch` marshalling issue). And what happens if you try using `MSXML2.XmlHttp`? And what happens if you try using `msxml2.XmlHttp` with early binding (i.e. `IXmlHttpRequest`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
ole.Send(FXMLDoc.XML.Text);
```

Can you get an approximation of your failure threshold? Is it within a consistent range?  Can you log what's actually been received by your server?

Having said that, I'd say you need to check your byte count - how many are actually getting sent over the wire? If increased size is causing intermittent failure, it may well be that you're not sending all of your content in one pass - you may have to keep track of the amount you've actually sent and loop until you are sure your entire stream content has actually been transmitted.

HTH

Comment: The threshold is about 50k.  We did check the server.  When there is a failure it is because the user and pass are blank.  The strange part is it's the exact same code when it works.

Comment: 'When there is a failure it is because the user and pass are blank' - do mean that there is more data after user and pass, that **is** being sent, just those fields are being skipped? If so, obviously my answer is not correct and you've got a security issue of some sort.

Comment: Have you tried comparing count of bytes you tried to transmit with count of bytes actually sent?

Comment: What I don't get is that you're sending user/pass separately from the XML doc - so why should the size of the XML doc impact user/pass. Also - you say the code has been working for many years: have their been changes in the environment, infrastructure, etc that might now be responsible for this new behavior? I do a lot of work along these lines so I find the problem interesting...